# service binder receives custom aidl callback interface as null

Tags: android, service, callback, aidl

I am passing a custom AIDL callback interface in a bound service. The service binder is receiving it as null.

The service and clients are running in separate processes. The request, response, service, binder, utility class for binding the service and callback stub adapter aidl and class are in a android library project which both the service and client classes (in separate applications) use.

Here are the relevant code (minus the imports). (Compiling fine, and no runtime exceptions)

```
// service callback IResponseReceiver.aidl
oneway interface IResponseReceiver {
    void onReceiveResponseA(in int statusCode, in ResponseA response);
    void onReceiveResponseB(in int statusCode, in ResponseB response);
}

// service aidl
oneway interface IService {
    void executeA(in RequestA request, in IResponseReceiver receiver);
    void executeB(in RequestB request, in IResponseReceiver receiver);
}

// service binder
public class ServiceImpl extends IService.Stub {
    private ExecutorService mExecutor;

    @Override
    public void executeA(RequestA request, IResponseReceiver receiver) throws RemoteException {
        mExecutor.execute(handle(request, receiver)); // receiver == null here
    }

    @Override
    public void executeB(RequestB request, IResponseReceiver receiver) throws RemoteException {
        mExecutor.execute(handle(request, receiver)); // receiver == null here
    }
}

// service callback adapter class
class ResponseReceiver extends IResponseReceiver.Stub {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResponseA(int statusCode, ResponseA response)
        throws RemoteException {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveResponseB(int statusCode, ResponseB response)
        throws RemoteException {
    }
}

// service callback class in client
class ClientResponseReceiver extends ResponseReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResponseB(int statusCode, ResponseB response)
        throws RemoteException {
        // do something
        }
}

// utility class for calling bound service method
class ServiceChannel implements ServiceConnection {
    private IService mService;

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }

    void execute(RequestA request, ResponseReceiver receiver) {
        mService.executeA(request, receiver); // receiver != null here
    }
}
```

The activity which calls startService() also calls startActivity(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) for the client app. The client app binds the service and calls IService.executeA().

What am I doing wrong? No stacktrace showing anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is null?  be more specific...

Comment: the receiver is null.

Comment: I think we need to see your service.  Where is the call to ServiceChannel.execute?

Comment: Client apps are calling channel.execute(requestA, new ClientResponseReceiver());

Comment: // this is my exported service
public class MyService extends Service {
    private IBinder mImpl = new ServiceImpl();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mImpl;
    }
}

Comment: Are you saying that your code reads: channel = new ServiceChannel(); channel.execute(something, new ClientResponseReceiver()), and that ServiceChannel.execute(...) sees null as its second argument?  ...or that ServiceImpl.executeA(...) sees null as it's second argument?

Comment: @blake: yes, the code reads channel = new ServiceChannel() and channel.execute(request, new ClientResponseReceiver()) in the client code. And ServiceImpl.executeA(...) sees null as it's second  argument.

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  Sorry that took so long.

The AIDL defs for the methods in IService take only one argument.  The second argument is not getting passed through Binder.  You need:

```
interface IService {
    void executeA(in RequestA request, in IResponseReceiver receiver);
    void executeB(in RequestB request, in IResponseReceiver receiver);
}
```

Comment: oops extremely sorry for the typo. my interface looks exactly like what you have defined. i have mistyped the aidl. Thanks mate.

Comment: sorry my comment looks confusing. i am still having the problem. the typo was in the stack overflow post, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

The service is started from App-1. App-1 also starts App-2 using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. App-2 tries to bind to the service.

Looks like FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In android AIDL you can't use normal java objects as callback or receiver because they are in different process.
consider using RemoteCallbackList;